# Is it possible to have both A record and URL redirect at same domain ? How to?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, domain, cname-record, a-record

Let's assume I have example.org. I want to redirect all request (URL redirect) to google.com
But I also want to have a A record on example.org that points to 127.0.0.1

So pinging example.org should ping to 127.0.0.1 but browsing example.org should browse to google.com.

Is this possible ? If yes how to mix this two ?

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Yup, +1. You could run a web server at 127.0.0.1 that redirects/proxies, or maybe have the firewall intercept port 80 traffic, I suppose.

Comment: Another thought was issuing ICMP redirects that only trigger on ICMP ECHOs but... just, no.